# Running a bash script before running a React instance in docker?

Tags: linux, reactjs, bash, docker

I'm trying to run a bash script in a docker container on initialization when the container runs before starting a CRA application. This bash script copies an environment variable `GCP_PROJECT_ID` to a `.env` file as defined by the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file. I tried using an `Entrypoint` to run the file but it doesn't work.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:9-alpine

RUN npm install yarn

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./yarn.lock /usr/app
COPY ./package.json /usr/app

RUN yarn install

COPY . /usr/app/

RUN yarn build

FROM node:9-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY --from=0 /usr/app/build /usr/app/build
COPY --from=0 /usr/app/package.json /usr/app/package.json
COPY .env /usr/app/.env
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/app/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/app/docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN yarn global add serve

RUN npm prune --production
ARG GCP_PROJECT_ID=xxxxx # SAMPLE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
ENV GCP_PROJECT_ID=$GCP_PROJECT_ID

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/app/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "serve", "build" ]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "\n" >> /usr/app/.env
printf "REACT_APP_GCP_PROJECT_ID=$GCP_PROJECT_ID" >> /usr/app/.env
```

I can verify that the environment variables do exist i.e. running `docker run -it --entrypoint sh <IMAGE NAME>` and `echo $GCP_PROJECT_ID` does print `xxxxx`.

How can I run a bash script before starting up my CRA application in docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ENTRYPOINT` script gets passed the `CMD` as arguments.  You need to include a line to tell it to actually run the command, typically `exec "$@"`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$GCP_PROJECT_ID" ]; then
  echo "REACT_APP_GCP_PROJECT_ID=$GCP_PROJECT_ID" >> /usr/app/.env
fi
exec "$@"
```

If you use this pattern, you don't need `--entrypoint`

```sh
sudo docker run -e GCP_PROJECT_ID=... imagename cat /usr/app/.env
# should include the REACT_APP_GCP_PROJECT_ID line
```

Depending on what else is in the file, it's common enough to use `docker run -v` to inject a config file wholesale, instead of trying to construct it at startup time.

```sh
sudo docker run -v $PWD/dot-env:/usr/app/.env imagename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` in `CMD` in `Dockerfile`

```
CMD sh /usr/app/docker-entrypoint.sh && serve build
```

or put `serve build` command into your script